# Can a stack just be thought of as an array with member functions?

Tags: arrays, stack

Assuming we are using an array implementation of a stack and not a linked-list implementation.

Comment: What context? Are you talking about a stack type collection, or a processor stack?

Comment: I mean stack type.. Sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. You can rather see a stack colletion as a wrapper around an array.

An array is allocated with a fixed size, while a stack grows with the data that is added to it. Generally this is done by allocating a small array initially, and allocate a larger array when the data outgrows the current array.